# Is there anyway to trap or kill a popup window when calling dll function via interop?

Tags: c#, interop, dllimport, messagebox

I am writing a C# application which calls a function within an DLL written using unmanaged code.

For the most part, the calls work fine and the called functions return an integer value specifying either success, or a handful of error codes. However, for a couple of the error codes, the DLL also seems to pop up a message box providing some further information regarding the error.

I have no way of knowing if this is going to occur for a given funciton call or not, and would rather not hassle the user with these message boxes, as sometimes I am calling this function thousands of times in a batch process and I would rather not have the user have to press "OK" for however many failures there happen to be.

If there is any way to either determine that a message box was shown after a given call, or alternatively generally disable or disallow any windows or forms to be displayed during a given call? It seems unlikely, but I thought I'd ask at any rate.

Thanks,
Mr M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect, you're not going to be able to suppress popups from code you haven't written, unless the calls have a specific parameter that would do that for you. Are the message boxes associated with particular error codes?

There are programs available that will monitor your computer for particular windows and click buttons on them when they appear, though of course requiring the users to run that as well is a bit of burden. [**EDIT**: Joe pointed out that you could do this yourself on a separate thread. Also an option.]

There are always going to be trade-offs when working with dependencies, and you have to balance the dependency's usefulness and necessity with what compromises it might require you to make.

Comment: You could always programmatically monitor for particular windows and click buttons on them. It's a bother, but it would address the burden of requiring users to run an additional app.

Comment: I had thought of this idea, but was hoping someone would just say, oh just add this "supressstupidpopup" attribute to your dllimport and you'll be fine. I think you guys are on the money though. I'll wait and see if someone comes up with something magical. Failing that, I have written to the maintainer of the library, but I'm not holding my breath :)

Comment: Just heard back from the producer of the DLL. While there isn't any such feature for this DLL, there is an alternative available that will hopefully provide the functionality I need minus the quirky MessageBox.

Answer (score 2):

Investigate low level Win API calls, they may offer a solution for you.

For example, using Spy++ can reveal window names which then you can search for and close.  Then using the WINDOWS API callouts...

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    // Get a handle to an application window.
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
        string lpWindowName);

    // Activate an application window.
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Then in a background thread, write a process that looks for these windows and closes them.

```
        //Some PsuedoCode, note loop should have a cancel condition!
        while (true)
        {
            //Get a handle.  
            handle = FindWindow(windowClassName,  windowName);

            //We found the window, close it
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //Send Close Command 
                SetForegroundWindow(handle);
                SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}");
            }

            //Wait 200ms seconds before trying again
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
```

You might be able to do some type of hackish solution like this in your application.

Note, you will have to store the windowClassName(s) and windowName(s) in some sort of config file or hardcode them in your application.

Comment: That looks really promising. Fortunately for me, I've just heard back from the guy who owns the DLL. While he hasn't fixed the issue or given me a workaround, he has pointed me to a very similar but updated DLL without the quirk. Thanks again for your response though. I'll probably take a look at Spy++ for the fun of it at any rate.

Comment: If you can get the owner of the DLL to suppress all user messages with some sort of parameter or option, that would be great.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no way to prevent an arbitrary (non-managed) DLL from popping up UI if it feels the need to do so.

One ugly work around though is to try and close the window immediately after it pops up.  The way I would do this would be to

- Start another thread.  It's job is to record the current active window for the process and close any new windows which show up.
- Make the call into the DLL
- Stop the thread

This is by no means a bullet proof process but it may help you work around this problem.

Comment: +1 for confirming my fears. Doesn't feel right to be upvoting for something that is causing me grief though.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be practical for you to run this code from inside a Windows service?

Services aren't allowed to show GUI (you used to be able to opt into allowing a service to show GUI, but MS has been phasing this out). I don't know for sure, but I think calls to MessageBox() and the like may simply return immediately when you call them from a non-interactive service.